# How to push to Heroku without database being reset

Tags: python, database, django, heroku

I have an app running on Heroku with a database attatched. But everytime i push my local project to heroku it resets the database to the one i'm pushing, os all the changes my app has done to the database is lost. I have tried to solve this a few different ways but nothing seems to work.

Comment: There must be code/config which is resetting your database.by default it should not update the records

Comment: The databse is located as a .sqlite3 file in the project, so everytime i push that file is replaced by the one in the commit

Comment: You must not and cannot use sqlite on Heroku. Use the proper db add-on.

Comment: You should use heroku postgres